# jquery document ready function not being called

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

For some reason I can't get the jquery document ready to fire for my plugin

my javascript

```
jquery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert("hello world");
    $("#testdiv").text("hi");
});
```

the source from my website

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css?ver=20111209' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fantasy_golf = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/example.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/fantasy-golf/js/fantasy-golf.js?ver=1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>
```

when I follow the source of my fantasy-golf.js (in firefox's source) it has the correct version of my js.  (it shouldn't be due to it caching an older version)

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. I'm not seeing how this is a **WordPress** question? You're using no-conflict mode (correctly), and your scripts are either hard-coded in your template, or else properly enqueued. That pretty much eliminates anything WordPress-specific.

Comment: I'll move it to stack overflow then...
I'm surprised since the plugin from this site does work.  http://www.itsananderson.com/2011/04/wordcamp-seattle-meta/  which is pretty much what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Don't re-post anything. If needed, we can migrate content from one site to another. For now, I'll leave this here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `jQuery` instead of `jquery`. (Note the capital "Q".)

Edit:

Upon viewing your source, you have an extra `});`.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Greug/)

Comment: I tried and tried again still no luck.

Comment: Do you have a link where we can view a sample page?

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing it a little differently.  Instead of

```
jquery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert("hello world");
    $("#testdiv").text("hi");
});
```

Try this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hello world');
        $('#testdiv').text('hi');
    });
})(jQuery);
```